# Drupal: strange goings on when upload to web server

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Hi I've been developing a drupal site on my local machine for a couple of weeks. Got myself a domain name and some hosting and uploaded it but I'm getting strange errors. Sometime I get 404 errors and soemtimes 500 erros when trying to load pages. Also, anything which is a sub folder of admin just displays a blank white screen.

Sometimes I get these errors, soemtimes not:

```
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected  to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'r05booy_tvn_get_form' was given in /home/r05booy/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348.
```

I have mod_rewrite on and friendly urls on the server. My database is set up and connecting ok.

I'm using version 6.

Thanks for any help or insite!

Jonesy

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the clearing cache suggestions I managed to fix this.

Since I couldn't get to the performance page I found an article on how to do this - http://drupal.org/node/42055.

I created a file called clear.php with the following code:

```
<?php
  include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
?>
```

Uploaded it to the root, then browsed to it. It fixed all my problems. **remember to delete the file afterwards!**

Comment: A tip for clearing cache, is to use drush: `drush cc all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't make a blank install, you'll need to clear the cache.

Anyways the error is coming from the menu system, which is trying to call `r05booy_tvn_get_form`. It looks like this is originating from a custom module you have made. Look at your hook_menu implementation.

Comment: how can I clear the cache if I can't navigate to the site config > performance page?

Comment: no matter, managed to clear my cache and it fied it. I've updated my question with how I did it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've moved your site to a new server and you've got white screen, the first thing to check is the php memory limit. But there other causes of white screen.

It looks like your menu router doesn't know the path to the files with the callback when it says "First argument is expected to be a valid callback".

Sometimes clearing your cache will fix this or browsing to the modules page in admin.

If your site runs in a sub folder somewhere or the path to your modules is not 'sites/all/modules' but something like 'sites/example.com/modules' you can have trouble moving the site from one place to another. take a look at the paths to your themes and modules in the system and the menu_router (or maybe menu_links) tables.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something like this when moving a multi site from one server to another.  No amount of jamming on the clear cache link, browsing to the modules page or any of the other methods would fix it. It turned out that cache had an entry in it with the old file locations that for some reason was not being cleared. In my case the specific problem was the location of the theme's css files.  Visiting the actual theme configuration and saving a simple configuration change finally fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't look obvious from the error, when I saw this some time ago, I think it turned out to be a missing CSS or image file for a theme.